# Add image to an RSS-item in Mailchimp-feed

Tags: xml, email, rss, feed, mailchimp

I need to add an image to my RSS feed, which shall be used with each item in my MailChimp campaigns.

I have tried to add this part to my RSS-feed, but I don't know if it's correct - and if it is, how to get the image path into my Mailchimp account.

```
<media:content url="{path_to_img}" medium="image" />
```

Hope someone can help

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post the url to the feed so we can review :)

Comment: Julien: My bad.. It's fixed now :)